# How to disable multiple selection of nodes in dijit.Tree?

Tags: dojo, selection, dijit.tree

How to set selection mode single in dijit.Tree? What I mean by selection mode single is user should not be able to select multiple nodes by making use of shift key or ctrl key + mouse click on node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selection is handled by `dijit/Tree::dndController`, which defaults to `dijit/tree/_dndSelector`. There is a property `singular` in `_dndSelector` and its documentation states:

> singular: Boolean
>
> Allows selection of only one element, if true.
>
> Tree hasn't been tested in singular=true mode, unclear if it works.

Anyway, it seems to work:

```
var tree = new dijit.Tree({
    id: "tree1",
    model: model
}).placeAt(win.body());

tree.dndController.singular = true;
```

Check it out at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/UxWUs/